# Temporarily full screen a pane in tmux

Tags: tmux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Maximizing” a pane in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/238702/maximizing-a-pane-in-tmux)

In tmux I would like to be able to make the currently active pane either full screen or become the only pane in a new window temporarily.  Then restore it to its original location and size.

I believe this is the same as the question: ["Maximizing" a pane in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/238702/maximizing-a-pane-in-tmux) but no answers were offered so I thought I would try a different wording / title.

Anyone have any ideas?