# tmux + iterm2 integration: can't maximize pane

Tags: tmux, iterm2

Is there a way to do this? By this, I mean if you have split panes, you were able to maximize a pane with iterm2 with `shift + command + enter`. I believe it's possible to do this in tmux as well based on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/238702/maximizing-a-pane-in-tmux).