# Change Tmux background colour of zoomed pane

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 and Tmux.

I would like to change the background colour of a Tmux pane but only when zoomed. I know there is a window_is_zoomed flag and I am wondering if I can us this in a if-shell statement or somewhere else to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this one-liner (split into multiple lines for readability) as an example:

```
tmux set-hook -g after-resize-pane \
'if "[ #{window_zoomed_flag} -eq 1 ]" \
    "run \"tmux select-pane -P bg=red\"" \
    "run \"tmux select-pane -P bg=black\""
'
```

Run it in a shell within `tmux` and zoom any pane to test the solution.

Notes:

- It's pure `tmux` solution, it doesn't depend on iTerm2.
- There are three levels of quoting (single-quotes, double-quotes, escaped double-quotes). While adjusting the command to your needs don't mix them up.
- `-g` means the hook is global; without `-g` it's a session hook.
- Unset the hook with `tmux set-hook -gu after-resize-pane`.
- To make the solution permanent, add this line to `~/.tmux.conf` (or `/etc/tmux.conf`):

  ```
    set-hook -g after-resize-pane 'if "[ #{window_zoomed_flag} -eq 1 ]" "run \"tmux select-pane -P bg=red\"" "run \"tmux select-pane -P bg=black\""'
  ```