# "Maximizing" a pane in gnu-screen

Tags: gnu-screen

Similar to ["Maximizing" a pane in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/238702/maximizing-a-pane-in-tmux/576505) is there a way to maximize a pane using screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not as familiar with tmux's "Maximize", but are you referring to "Command-Key"-Q ?

Or if your command key is Ctrl-A, it would be Ctrl-A-Q

It's the "only" command.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. For tmux maximize, its command-key+z, and its a toggle so if you do command-key+z again, the windows go back to their previous orientation. Seems like command-key+Q in screen is not a toggle....when I hit it again, nothing happens. Is there another shortcut to go back to previous window orientation?

Comment: Not per se, there are ways of saving and then restoring the window layout in screen, but I don't know of a "Maximize" toggle.